# What Intent does an Alarm Clock broadcast?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

On [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) it says

> When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered for it is broadcast by the system, automatically starting the target application if it is not already running.

What Intent does the regular Alarm Clock broadcast? So that I can assign a Broadcast Receiver to listen for it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to receive intent broadcasted by default Alarm Clock application? Or your own intent in your alarm clock set by `void setAlarmClock (AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo info, 
                PendingIntent operation)`?

Comment: I wanted to receive the intent broadcasted when the regular alarm goes off, so yeah, the one broadcasted by the default Alarm Clock application. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
 filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
 this.sysForbidenReceiver.checkTime(this);
 this.registerReceiver(this.sysForbidenReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try it out tomorrow and accept your solution if it works! :)

Comment: hey did this work ? u r saying that when i schedule an alarm from my phones alarm clock ...the one that comes built in , i will be able to catch the broadcast receiver for it via the above code ..!

Comment: Well, technically it works, ACTION_TIME_TICK is broadcasted every minute, and since the system alarm clock can only be set to rounded minutes (no seconds) the ACTION_TIME_TICK will be called at the same time as the alarm alert. 

tl;dr no, this isn't the correct answer